# Why does CShort(True) = -1

Tags: vb.net, boolean, type-conversion

Why does the following code print out its below value, specifically with regards to the `CShort` method in VB.Net?

```
Console.WriteLine(CShort(False)) 'prints 0
Console.WriteLine(CShort(True)) 'prints -1
```

I have been able to reproduce this with many of the [Visual Basic type conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx).

Was this just a design decision in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[In Visual Basic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic#Characteristics), the Boolean data type is stored as a 16 bit signed integer.

In this representation , -1 evaluates to 16 one bits and 0 is, of course, 16 zero bits.

Hence, if you want the relationship `True = Not False` to hold, then True must have the value -1.

Comment: This makes sense. Do you have a reference or citation for it?

Comment: Wikipedia does a better job at explaining it: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic

Comment: Thank you, I added the link and will accept it once I can.

Comment: Parhaps replace `In Visual Basic` with `In .NET`

Answer (score 1):

It's not a VB-specific thing - all VB does is implicitly cast it for you to short.
In C#, you get the same result with an explicit call to a System.Convert method - e.g., System.Convert.ToInt16(true).

Comment: Not exactly the same, `System.Convert.ToInt16(true)` returns `1`.